# Using $HOME in Common Lisp paths? Executable fails

Tags: linux, macos, common-lisp, executable, sbcl

My main dev environment is a Mac M1.

I sometimes also develop on an Intel mac and then deploy to a linux server. All of which have different home paths.

Ideally, id like to have a dynamic path.

This is the hardcoded M1 path:

```lisp
(defvar *document* "/Users/vinceM1/quicklisp/local-projects/Project/web/")
```

Id like to have something like this:

```lisp
(defvar *document* "$HOME/quicklisp/local-projects/Project/web/")
```

However, when creating an executable, the path with $HOME isn't recognised. Is there a way to use dynamic OS paths so i can capture `/Users/vinceM1` or `/home/server/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Home directory

The interpolation of `$HOME` in pathnames is not part of the language standard and not supported in any implementation I know. Some implementations support the tilde notation `"~"` to refer to the home directory. But if you want to be portable, your best option is to use [`USER-HOMEDIR-PATHNAME`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_user_h.htm).

For example:

```
(defvar *document* (merge-pathnames "path/to/www" (user-homedir-pathname)))
=> #P"/home/user/path/to/www"
```

#### ASDF systems

In your example you define the document relative to some of your project. In fact, you can be portable in a different way by using [`ASDF:SYSTEM-RELATIVE-PATHNAME`](https://asdf.common-lisp.dev/asdf/Miscellaneous-Functions.html):

```
(defvar *document* (asdf:system-relative-pathname :project "www/"))
=> #P"/home/user/quicklisp/local-projects/project/www"
```

The paths are relative to the directory where the `.asd` file defining the given system is.

#### Environment variables

In case you really need to access an environment variable, you can rely on [`osicat`](https://osicat.common-lisp.dev/) to do that:

```
(probe-file (osicat-posix:getenv "HOME"))
=> #P"/home/user/"
```

I am using `probe-file` to convert a string to a pathname ending with a `/` (a directory).

Comment: I still have so much to learn. thanks again Coredump.

Comment: Simply `(uiop:getenv "HOME")` here!